# How to deal with a pointer type parameter in pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

In my c++ code, I have a function like:

```
bool some_function(std::vector<float>* result){
    result->append(1);
    result->append(2);
    return true;
}
```

I will update the result vector in "some_function".

I want to use pybind11 to bind this function.

```
#include<pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include<pybind11/stl.h>

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.def("some_function", &some_function);
}
```

Then in my python code, I want to use this function like this way:

```
result = []
is_success = some_function(result)
```

I expected the result to be updated like: `result = [1, 2]`

but actually `result = []`, still empty.

Please help me how to deal with the pointer parameter in pybind11. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659924/returning-numpy-arrays-via-pybind11

Comment: How about the function is a class function? How to deal with it? @πάνταῥεῖ